# How to automate generation of htpasswd from command line without typing password?

Tags: bash, .htpasswd

I am trying to automate creating a password from the command line.
I have tried the below but it still keeps asking for the password.

```
echo "test101" | htpasswd -c ~/temp/password admin
```

How to generate automate `htpasswd` from command line without typing password?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Why not just use:

```
htpasswd -b -c ~/temp/password admin test101
```

Comment: Although it's old: Because all other users on the same system may be able see "test101" in /proc/<uid>/cmdline for a short moment, if they are watching.

Comment: This is the case if your system has more than 1 users, for creating initial example to setup a server and generate htpasswd, this will have no problem.

Answer (score 22):

If you don't have `htpasswd` installed (for example when using nginx) you can generate a password with openssl.

```
printf "USER:$(openssl passwd -crypt PASSWORD)\n" >> .htpasswd
```

Comment: `-crypt` is considered insecure today. You can use `-apr1` instead.

Comment: Nginx also accepts SHA-256, that's even better then APR1 (MD5), for that use `-5` instead.

Comment: @GustavoVargas I've used this in the past but now it gives an error: `passwd: Option unknown option -5`.

Comment: @FabianBarney maybe your openssl is outdated. Take a look on this openssl command line reference: https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/openssl_passwd.1.asp

Answer (score 13):

The `-b` switch should do the trick, but the password will still be visible to other users on the system via the process list (`ps` etc):

```
htpasswd -b -c ~/temp/password admin test101
```

Answer (score 11):

From the man page of htpasswd we get this:

> -i     Read the password from stdin without verification (for script usage).

So just acording to your question something like this should work:

```
echo "test101" | htpasswd -c -i ~/temp/password admin
```

But the password will be visible in history and process list.

To automate creating a password from the command line i would write the plain password to a file and do something like that:

```
htpasswd -c -i ~/temp/password admin < ~/temp/pass_plain
```

Afterwards delete the pass_plain file.

Also make sure the pass_plain file is not readable by anyone else, also if its just there for a few seconds.

Comment: This feature was added between httpd-tools-2.2.15-69 (CentOS 6) and before httpd-tools-2.4.6-88 (CentOS 7) so it is not universally available.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install apache2-utils` in case of ubuntu

Comment: To avoid the history/process list issue, wouldnt it be easier and simpler to just cat and pipe? Something like `cat ~/temp/pass_plain | htpasswd -c -i ~/temp/password admin`?